# How to capture Mouse and Keyboard data across all websites for Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

Just as the title implies. How would I go about capturing general event data across websites? This is supposed to be a strictly client-side application. Would a chrome extension work? If so, how would I go about it? Does one already exist, or at least an alternative method?

Comment: I'm not sure how detailed an answer you require... In short, declare a *content script* that will have [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Events) listeners inside.

Comment: I am not very familiar with javascript at all. If I had the money, I'd have paid someone to teach me. I do know enough what a content script is, though. As detailed as you'd like to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In chrome extension, [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) are scripts that run in the context of web pages. You could listent to specific events (such as [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) and [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) ) just like normal scripts.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
}
```

content.js

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    console.log('mouse down');
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    console.log('key down');
}, false);
```

Comment: Can you explain the third parameter? Why is there a "false" after the function?

Comment: @Xenorosth, see `useCapture` part https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: There's no need to use it, [it has been optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility) in Chrome since its very first version, and in Firefox since v6.